# Does it require a DAD when generating link-local address in IPv6

Tags: ipv6, ip-link-local

In IPv4, link-local addresses are checked to be unique using an ARP request. But in IPv6, as it is generated by a EUI-64 or hash. It is assumed to be unique (I suppose). But does it require a DAD (Neighbor Solicitation and Advertisement) to do an extra confirmation. I have looked through the RFCs and didn't see an exact specification on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course IPv6 requires DAD for stateless addressing. See *[IPv6 Stateless Address Autoconfiguration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862.html)*, Section 5.4. Duplicate Address Detection:

> **[5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862.html#section-5.4).  Duplicate Address Detection**
>
> Duplicate Address Detection MUST be performed on all unicast addresses
> prior to assigning them to an interface, regardless of whether they
> are obtained through stateless autoconfiguration, DHCPv6, or manual
> configuration, with the following exceptions:
>
> - An interface whose DupAddrDetectTransmits variable is set to zero    does not perform Duplicate Address Detection.
> - Duplicate Address Detection MUST NOT be performed on anycast
>   addresses (note that anycast addresses cannot syntactically be
>   distinguished from unicast addresses).
> - Each individual unicast address SHOULD be tested for uniqueness.
>   Note that there are implementations deployed that only perform
>   Duplicate Address Detection for the link-local address and skip
>   the test for the global address that uses the same interface
>   identifier as that of the link-local address.  Whereas this
>   document does not invalidate such implementations, this kind of
>   "optimization" is NOT RECOMMENDED, and new implementations MUST
>   NOT do that optimization.  This optimization came from the
>   assumption that all of an interface's addresses are generated from
>   the same identifier.  However, the assumption does actually not
>   stand; new types of addresses have been introduced where the
>   interface identifiers are not necessarily the same for all unicast
>   addresses on a single interface [RFC4941] [RFC3972].  Requiring
>   that Duplicate Address Detection be performed for all unicast
>   addresses will make the algorithm robust for the current and
>   future special interface identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

If the address is generated via EUI-64, it can safely be assumed to be unique. On ethernet, if the MAC isn't unique, there will be other problems. Any self generated address(es) *must* be verified unique because they could be duplicated.